# How would I have a audio file playing in a method in Java, but then when that method is called again, the previous audio file is stopped playing?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

So I'm trying to make a guitar simulator, where if I call a method, that note plays. However, when I call it again, the previous sounds stops playing.

```
    public class ytst {
         public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
             Estring.play(1);
             TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
     Estring.play(2);
    }
    ----------
    class Estring{
         public static play(int fret){
            String filename="E" + fret + ".wav"
            File soundFile = new File(filename);
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
         }
    }
```

When i try this, the second audio file just overlaps the first. How can i make it so when I call this methd again the previous sound file stops playing?

Answer (score 1):

Clips were designed to hold sounds that are reused. Before they will play, the entire .wav file has to be loaded into memory. This can create problems with lag. SourceDataLines will start playing much more quickly, because they only load a buffer's worth of data before starting to play.

Where Clips shine is in starting or restarting them *after* they have been loaded into memory. Since they are running from memory, there is no costly file loading happening as there is with SourceDataLines. So, if you are going to use Clips, consider first initializing all the Clips. If this consumes too much memory, I would stick with SourceDataLines, at least for a first pass at your app, before trying anything fancy to optimize.

To stop a Clip, all you have to do is call clip.stop(). I'd consider doing something like creating a variable called currentClip, and stopping it with this method, then reassigning it with the value of the new note that you wish to play. If the currentClip is volatile, it should respond quickly even if the various notes are being played on different threads.

With SourceDataLine, you can do the same sort of thing, though shutting down a SourceDataLine is a bit more involved. A common strategy is to have a volatile "playing" boolean as a condition in the innermost while loop. You can set the "playing" variable to false and the sourceDataLine thread will shut down, assuming you have written it correctly--there are good examples of this in the Java Tutorials, the Sound section.